# Load all or just a part?

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, search, web

We are going to display a list of 25-entries on a webpage out of (at least) 5000 entries in the database. The entries should be sortable and you should be able to filter the results according to their names.

In my world, you send a request to the server asking for 25 entries that matches your criterion. However my colleague suggested a different approach; to ask for all 5000 entries and then sort and filter them with JavaScript.

I think that's stupid, but I'm afraid I'm missing something. What would you say are the pros and cons of this two approaches?

Comment: This is a vague question. It all depends really. How much information does the list hold? Also you should consider something in between 25 and 5000. Right now it just seems that this is a battle of ideologies and not a technical question at all. Furthermore I do not know who said it but "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: Implement both, measure. (Or even better: implement either one, if it works well, use it. If not, try the other one.)

Comment: Your bottleneck is always going to be the database in a large website. Therefore, you put the least load on it possible, and get 25 rows rather than 5,000.

Comment: One item is about 100 bytes.

I don't understand how I can have something between 25 and 5000. With all 5000 loaded I can sort the list without any server communication. With only a part of the whole database loaded I still will need to communicate with the server for every sort and then the "load 25-entries" solution will best.

Today the database is currently about 40 000 entries (this is expected to be lowered) and the initial pageload take seconds when loading all 40000 entries. However repeated sorting is fast. I guess it's all about how slow a webpage is allowed to be...

Comment: At least 5000? So at the end it can be 100k? It's too many to hold to client, 5000 is yet OK.

Comment: @GEMI: Donald Knuth said that.

Comment: You're asking us for advice on a trade-off, yet we have to guess at the parameters influencing the trade-off. I'd say that at least server load, client capacity (memory, processor), network bandwidth, network latency and worst-case size are relevant here. Unfortunately, these variables are not orthogonal. Note that worst-case list size has a heavy effect on the other variables as well

Answer (score -1):

Or use AJAX, returning HTML, for the next/ prev paging. That could give you a nice solution.

Then you don't have the white screen, the UI tends to appear more slick & responsive, you can write a nice (clean & simple) server handler & your colleague can be happy writing some JQuery & AJAX.

It keeps the app scalable, to any number of rows, and the UI is more slick & responsive..  which was perhaps the point of the JS idea.